# problemas con angualr 15 + firebase para encontrar collections

Tags: angular, firestore

Estoy aprendiendo angular 15 y firebase, viendo varios tutos me encuentro que usan collections desde Firestore pero en la nueva version no esta en Firestore.
Mi codigo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmpleadoService {
constructor(private readonly firestore: Firestore ) {}

agregarEmpleado(empleado: any){
   return this.firestore.collection('empleados').add(empleado)
 }
}
```

en el return, en **firestore** me marca un error: 'Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore'.'